# ¿Y si los votos de cierre se mostraran al AP = autor de la pregunta?

Tags: característica-nueva, cierre-de-preguntas, usuarios-nuevos, votos-de-cierre

Cuando uno pregunta y alguien vota para cerrar como duplicado, el sistema muestra al autor (AP = *autor de la pregunta*) un mensaje diciendo: dicen que la pregunta podría ser equivalente a esta otra, ¿es cierto eso? Edita para clarificarlo si no es el caso o marca como duplicada si sí lo es.
Esto resulta útil y hace ver al AP esta información de forma fácil y resuelve bastantes dudas.

Pero no es ese el único caso de voto de cierre. Como sabemos, existen muchos otros: por demasiado amplia, por no estar claro lo que se pregunta, por estar en un idioma distinto del castellano... Y en muchas ocasiones la gente, con buen criterio, vota por esos motivos pero el AP no es consciente de ello. Pasan las horas, se acumulan los votos de cierre, pero no se llega al quinto y definitivo. En todo ese tiempo el AP seguramente esté intrigado por saber la respuesta a su pregunta, pero no recibe información alguna. En efecto, hasta llegar a los 250 puntos, los usuarios no pueden ver los votos de cierre ([Privilegios -> Ver votos de cierre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)).

Me pregunto: ¿sería posible que el AP tuviera información sobre los votos de cierre que está recibiendo? Creo que esto sería especialmente útil con los nuevos usuarios, para interactuar con ellos en esos primeros minutos que son el tiempo que sabemos que están allí, pues pasadas las horas, cuando se cierra la pregunta, la información de "demasiado amplia" tal vez ya no llegue a verla y simplemente nos encontremos con una pregunta algo mala de la que nadie más responda nunca y que no clarificará porque la información le llega tarde.

¿Qué os parece?

Nótese que con esto no evado cuestiones importantes de:

1. Que es importante comentar a los usuarios nuevos y facilitar el aterrizaje en el sitio.
2. Que las preguntas es importante que se formulen bien.
3. Que hay mucha gente haciendo tanto 1 como 2 de forma espléndida :)

Answer (score 7):

Me parece muy buena idea, expongo mis razones:

- Los usuarios nuevos, se llegan a sentir confundidos por que en ocasiones piensan que no existe alguien con conocimiento técnico para apoyarles, pero esto que comentas ayudaría a que comprendieran mejor por que pasan hrs. sin recibir ayuda alguna (no siempre las preguntas con problemas de formato reciben comentarios indicando lo que les falla, simplemente acumulan vistas)
- A la par que se pueden estar recibiendo los votos de cierre, por alguna de las razones que tú ya mencionas y que la mayoría conocemos, el `AP` se entera y complementa su aprendizaje con los enlaces que le dejemos en la zona de comentarios

Es decir de lo anterior, podemos comprender que ayuda a que los usuarios nuevos, asimilen que las observaciones, el no recibir respuestas y los votos de cierre corresponden a las reglas de la comunidad desde un punto de vista objetivo y sin afán de daño o maltrato.

Si recordamos hace poco algún usuario exponía aquí mismo en *Meta* que se pudiera incluir el asistente para la redacción de preguntas, lo cual aunado a que el `AP` pueda ver si esta recibiendo votos de cierre mas los comentarios objetivos de guía que se le dejen; serán de apoyo a:

- Comprender que se hizo mal y como mejorarlo
- Reducir tiempos en la edición de la pregunta para mejorarla
- El `AP` se va familiarizando mas y mas con las reglas del sitio
- Conoce el impacto que una pregunta mal realizada puede tener(cierre en este caso)
- Reducir tiempos de espera para que el `AP` revise si su pregunta sea respondida o no

  - Si la pregunta es basada en opiniones, sabrá mas rápido como proceder a mejorarla o eliminarla
  - Si la pregunta solo le hace falta una mejor redacción o poner el código mínimo necesario o inclusive corregir las *tags* usadas

Comment: ¡Lo explicaste mucho mejor que yo! Muchas gracias por el apoyo a la propuesta