# ¿Por qué no se puede marcar como duplicada una pregunta si ninguna de las dos tiene respuestas? O ¿cómo proceder en ese caso?

Tags: discusión

El día de hoy me he topado con dos preguntas, en la etiqueta [pascal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal), que, a mi manera de ver, son en realidad la misma pregunta.

- [Dígitos leídos y suma de esos dígitos en PASCAL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/255042/21) de [MatiPHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/89604/matiphp)
- [¿Cómo sumar dígitos en pascal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/255063/21) de [MatiST00](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/85459/matist00)

Al intentar marcarla como duplicada, veo esto:

[image: No puedo marcarla como duplicada]

¿cómo se debe proceder en este caso?

Porque, creo que tan es la misma pregunta que, siendo de distinto autor, el código es increíblemente similar:

- Código de la pregunta 1:

  [image: Imagen de la pregunta 1]
- Código de la pregunta 2:

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que solo hay que buscar por el título de la pregunta y no por el enlace exacto.

Answer (score 7):

El objetivo de marcar como duplicado a una pregunta no es a per se cerrar la pregunta.

Al menos yo solo conozco 2 motivaciones para marcar como duplicado:

1. Indicar al AP que ya antes alguien realizo la misma pregunta obteniendo buenas respuestas(respuesta con puntaje positivo o es una respuesta aceptada por el AP) que considero que son la solución a la nueva pregunta ya que eso ahorraria tiempo al AP y recursos a la comunidad.
2. Muchas veces el AP por diversos motivos(desconocimiento, desesperación, querer atraer atención, etc) publica la misma pregunta en varias publicacione lo cual es considerado como ruido a la comunidad.

Pero en el caso en que señalas no veo motivación, en estos casos mi análisis inicia poniendome en la posición del AP: *si yo tuviera un problema X que haciendo la búsqueda veo que ya alguien pregunto pero no recibio ninguna respuesta ¿Publicaria la misma pregunta?*, en mi caso sí lo haria ya que quiero una respuesta, ya que quizas cuando el otro AP hizo la pregunta no hubo los expertos que pudieran responderla y quizas ahora tenga suerte, porque quizas mi pregunta este mejor planteada que la anterior pregunta, etc.

El caso que indicas solo podria pensar en cerrarlo si sospecho que fue realizado por la misma persona con diferentes cuentas en períodos cortos de tiempo, pero para ello se debe hacer un análisis más profundo. Pero la acción no lo podemos hacer con nuestros poderes por lo que lo reportaria para que lo analice un moderador diamantado que tiene más herramientas para hacer la investigación y poderes para sancionarlo si lo considera necesario.

Y por último que tengan un código similar no indica que sean duplicados ya que muchas veces usamos como base el código que vemos en tutoriales, documentación, etc.

Comment: Creo que es muy probable que estemos ante el caso No. 2, solo que el **OP** utiliza 2 cuentas distintas.

Comment: ¿Qué significa AP? Pregunto porque supongo que te refieres al autor de la pregunta y yo, en ese caso, utilizo OP, que viene de SO en inglés: _Original Poster_. Nunca había leído el término AP. Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate Quise usar AP ya que estamos en SOes como tradución de OP, lo tome de https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4046

Comment: @jachguate ¿Tienes pruebas de qué estemos en el caso 2?, además el caso señala que es el mismo usuario que es diferente a misma persona. Una persona puede tener varios usuarios

Comment: Gracias por el dato, no había visto el término, lo adopto a partir de ahora. Sobre si el código, casualmente, podría venir del Internet, he hecho una búsqueda antes de publicar mi pregunta y estoy convencido que no: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-b-d&ei=Cm22XIm_NMXfwALM1KvgCA&q=%22cont%2Cdig%2Csuma%3AInteger%22&oq=%22cont%2Cdig%2Csuma%3AInteger%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...18108.19637..20146...0.0..0.191.382.0j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.k9atgQhys5U

Comment: @jachguate y ¿si ambos usuarios llevaron un mismo curso/clase y ese el código del tutor en iguales o diferentes períodos?

Comment: ¿Y ambos casualmente se llaman Mati?, jeje, no sé. No puedo afirmar categóricamente que se trata de una misma persona, pero tiene muchos síntomas de serlo. Y si ese código lo hubiese dado el tutor, bueno, mejor sería que se cambiasen de escuela. :D

Comment: @jachguate como señalo en mi respuesta quienes tienen que analizar esos casos deben ser lo moderadores diamantados :-)

Comment: Claro, no lo discuto, traigo el caso aquí para ver cual es el sentir de la comunidad y de los moderadores mismos. Un saludo.

Comment: No puedo discutir las cuestiones sobre si el usuario es el mismo o no. Pero lo que si puedo asegurar, es que por lo menos uno esta estudiando en algun tipo de curso, y ya se quejo de su profesor (tuvo una charla conmigo en una de sus preguntas).

Comment: @gbianchi una consulta ¿Puedes ver las IPs de los usuarios? Quizás así puedes verificar ello

Comment: @eyllanesc El sistema por si mismo reporta cosas sospechas y si ustedes lo traen a meta todavia mejor ;).

Comment: una forma de resolverlo es dejar un comentario del tipo : posiblemente relacionado ( y el link a la otra pregunta ). O responder la mas antigua y luego marcar duplicado

Comment: @aloMalbarez Sobre el punto 2, responder a la pregunta antigua no la hace elegible para que sea un duplicado de la pregunta actual ya que para ello es necesario que tenga un puntaje >= 1 o ser aceptado(lo último es complicado ya que las preguntas antiguas generalmente no son aceptadas). IMHO prefiero responder la pregunta actual, y marcar como duplicado si se puede a la pregunta antigua.

Comment: @eyllanesc no hace falta que sea aceptada, necesita una respuesta. si la respuesta no es cualquier cosa recibirá votos y por ende la pregunta puede ser la "canónica"

Comment: @aloMalbarez necesita una respuesta con al menos 1 voto, eso lo señale en mi comentario: *... es necesario que tenga un puntaje >= 1 o ...*, eso de canónico es relativo. Prefiero responder la pregunta que actualmente tenga atención o la que tenga una mejor pregunta :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc son preferencias personales y un efecto secundario de la gamificación, cualquier forma sirve, si hay respuesta y es válida recibirá votos, si te interesa ganar puntos por un aceptado ya es decisión personal.

Comment: @aloMalbarez Tienes razon en parte, pero yo lo señalaba porque una buena pregunta, no en el sentido del fondo de la pregunta ya que como son duplicados no es necesario discutir, sino en la forma ya que una pregunta buena + una respuesta buena le sirve más a la comunidad :-)