# Juntos por el bien de la comunidad: ¿Qué problemas sobre la comunidad ves?

Tags: discusión

Muchas gracias a [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) por la traducción.

---

Es imposible aprender algo si no sabes nada al respecto: es extremadamente importante qué conocimiento existe y hasta qué punto está disponible. El problema de crear, acumular y mantener el conocimiento de programación es el mismo en todo el mundo, pero adopta diferentes formas en diferentes idiomas, debido a las diferencias en la cultura y la historia de una comunidad en particular. Por ejemplo, si uno mira Stack Overflow en inglés, ven una característica única: antes de que se lanzara el sitio, había dos problemas críticos en ese momento:

- No había una base de conocimiento estructurada. Encontrar una respuesta a cualquier pregunta era muy difícil y tomaba mucho tiempo.
- Los resultados de búsqueda estaban llenos de enlaces a sitios que no mostraban contenido de personas hasta que se pagaba por el acceso al sitio.

Todo el mundo sufría, sin excepción. El punto de inflexión en la vida de la comunidad de habla inglesa sucedió cuando las personas comenzaron a trabajar juntos en estos problemas: lanzaron Stack Overflow y comenzaron a reunir conocimientos sobre el sitio bajo la licencia CC-BY-SA.

Creo que Stack Overflow en español tiene una buena posibilidad de convertirse en una de las fuentes clave de conocimiento en el idioma español, similar a lo que Stack Overflow en inglés se ha convertido en la vida de los desarrolladores de habla inglesa. Para lograr este éxito, debemos trabajar juntos para resolver los problemas críticos de toda la comunidad hispanohablante. El primer paso en este camino es recopilar los problemas de la comunidad que vemos. Luego, discutir y seleccionar los que nos gustaría resolver. A continuación, resolveremos juntos los problemas seleccionados por el bien de la comunidad.

"Un largo camino empieza siempre con un primer paso". ¡Sugiero que comencemos ya nuestro viaje! Comparte tus reflexiones sobre los problemas de la comunidad que tú o tus colegas observáis. Para facilitar el proceso de análisis, he preparado varias preguntas de apoyo. Por favor, completa tus pensamientos sobre los problemas de la comunidad en forma de respuestas a estas preguntas.

**Ten en cuenta**: Por *comunidad* en las preguntas a continuación, me refiero a todos los desarrolladores de software que hablan español en general, no solo a los usuarios españoles.

1. ¿Qué problemas experimentas personalmente al buscar respuestas a tus preguntas de programación en el idioma español en Internet? ¿Qué te causa mayor frustración? ¿Cómo mejorarías esto?
2. ¿Dónde encuentras actualmente respuestas a las preguntas de programación? ¿Qué ves como el principal problema en estos sitios? ¿Cómo los resolverías?
3. ¿En qué gastas más tiempo buscando una respuesta? ¿Cómo mejorarías este proceso?
4. ¿Cuál es el problema común que la mayoría de los desarrolladores de habla hispana experimentan?
5. ¿Qué impide a la comunidad crear una base de conocimiento gratuita en el idioma español? ¿Cómo resolverías este problema?
6. ¿Le preguntas a tus colegas de programación *fuera de línea*? ¿Cómo se ve este proceso? ¿Cómo mejorarías este proceso?

¡Únete a la discusión e invita a tus colegas a participar! El todo es mayor que la suma de sus partes.

---

Si deseas responder estas preguntas de forma anónima, utiliza [este formulario de Google](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1j4DXzppERkla1sWB9O3ObG3tWtk3aZiv7b9FzrbWpqc/viewform). Tendremos en cuenta todos los análisis anónimos en futuras discusiones.

Answer (score 12):

Creo que uno de los principales problemas que afecta a la comunidad hispanohablante (y básicamente a todas las comunidades que no son anglosajonas) es el uso *lenguaje técnico* y traducciones.

**¿A qué me refiero con esto?**

La gran mayoría de los lenguajes de programación modernos usan palabras clave en inglés ( *while, if, List, Connection, Class*, etc.. ), y es algo generalmente conocido que si buscas algo en específico, es mas probable que encuentres respuestas en in inglés pues es el idioma universal.

Me he percatado leyendo las preguntas de es.SO que abundan tanto las preguntas que usan lenguaje técnico ( [Buscar un array por uno de sus valores dentro de otro array en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259120/buscar-un-array-por-uno-de-sus-valores-dentro-de-otro-array-en-php) ) como preguntas que traducen estos conceptos ( [Insertar dato de un arreglo a otro arreglo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207727/insertar-dato-de-un-arreglo-a-otro-arreglo) ) lo cual puede dificultar encontrar la respuesta que necesitas, pues no es posible saber si la respuesta existe, pero está escrita en lenguaje técnico, o con alguna traducción. Algunas de las palabras que he notado que suelen usarse tanto en lenguaje técnico como sus traducciones incluyen (y no se limita):

- Connection
- List
- Array
- Group
- Host
- Key
- DB
- Link

Tomando en cuenta que he notado también el uso de AP (Autor de la Pregunta) como dice en [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4046/y-si-los-votos-de-cierre-se-mostraran-al-ap-autor-de-la-pregunta) y que al parecer mucha gente en meta concuerda en su uso, pienso que debería haber una especie de "regla" en la que se fomente el uso de un solo idioma, ya sea la traducción de estos conceptos a español o estar de acuerdo en solo usar lenguaje técnico.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que encontrar respuestas en español es especialmente complejo debido a la mayor diversidad de formas de expresarnos sin embargo no creo que en un espacio abierto e incluyente como este podamos hacer un acuerdo como el que propones en lo que a los títulos y cuerpo de las preguntas y respuestas en general pero confío en que sí podemos hacerlo en cuanto a las preguntas/respuestas canónicas y las principales etiquetas.

Comment: El problema que ilustra @Killbunny es externo a SO (motres de búsqueda) no interno (uso del sitio). Tal vez exista alguna manera de comunicar a los motores de búsqueda que si alguien usando español como idioma busca "array", debe buscar también textos con "arreglo", "matriz", "vector" o "formación".

Comment: ¡Buen punto! Lo de _AP_ lo acuñé yo hace poco al ver que en SOpt lo hacen. Por qué no hacerlo nosotros también :) A ver si cuaja jeje.

Comment: En [Diccionario de términos técnicos en castellano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3381/83) listamos traducciones _canónicas_ de términos usados en el sitio. No es sobre programación en sí, sino sobre interfaz del sitio. Dicho lo cual, veo difícil consensuar términos informáticos, pues el rango de gente que usa el sitio es tan amplio (en edad, localización, experiencia, familiaridad con el inglés) que difícilmente haya términos reconocidos por todos. Dicho lo cual, con buenas etiquetas y títulos claros, la confusión debería ir a menos (ejemplo: hacer [tag:arreglo] y [tag:array] sinónimas)

Comment: ¿De verdad `[arreglo]` y `[array]` aún no son sinónimos?

Comment: No recuerdo que hayamos hablado de cosas que la comunidad podría hacer para mejorar el SEO... ¿será?

Comment: Creo que los incisos 1, 3 y 4 están claramente relacionados con mi respuesta, pues es un problema al encontrar respuestas. No solo se llega a una respuesta de SO por Google... Aunque no sé que tanto la gente use el mismo buscador de SOes.

Comment: Asumo que no mucha gente usa el buscador de SOes por lo general, incluyéndome, por lo general se hace más fácil buscar en Google, pero si existiesen sinónimos en las búsquedas, ahí sí quizás tendría el valor agregado que lleve a su uso imagino

Answer (score 9):

> ¿Qué problemas experimentas personalmente al buscar respuestas a sus preguntas de programación en el idioma español en Internet? ¿Qué causa la mayor frustración?

En mi opinión, el principal problema es el volumen de usuarios. SOes (100+k usuarios) tiene un ~1% de los usuarios de SOen (10+M usuarios). Dentro de los 10M de usuarios de SOen deben haber hispanohablantes que no estén participando en SOes. Cuantos más usuarios, más contenido. Me frustra que muchos usuarios de calidad hispanohablantes (o políglotas) no participen en el sitio en Español.

> ¿Cómo mejorarías esto?

Primero, deberíamos averiguar por qué un usuario veterano de SOen que pudiera participar en SOes no lo hace. También deberíamos averiguar por qué un usuario nuevo pudiendo elegir entre SOes y SOen se decanta por el segundo, mis teorías y propuestas son las siguientes:

**Un veterano no quiere empezar de cero**: Un usuario experimentado en SOen con un medallero y reputación consolidados, no querría empezar de cero en un sitio con la misma temática.

- **Propuesta**: *Reputación a nivel de cuenta*: Para sitios de igual temática pero diferente idioma, la reputación podría ser común, o bien las cuentas SOes y SOen (y SO de cualquier idioma) se podrían fusionar en una sola. Esto no garantiza que el usuario veterano participe en sitios de otro idioma, pero al menos no pone la barrera de empezar de cero.

**Falta de visibilidad**: Puede no ser suficientemente obvio para todos los usuarios que existe una versión de SO en Español.

- **Propuesta**: *Una campaña (más) agresiva* de visibilidad.

> ¿Dónde encuentras respuestas en las preguntas de programación de hoy? ¿Qué ves como el principal problema en estos sitios? ¿Cómo los resolverías?

Mi principal fuente de información nunca ha sido SO, siempre ha sido Google. Si bien es cierto que el 95% de las veces google ofrece la respuesta en SO, el 99% de las veces no hago la búsqueda del problema en SO. Hay ciertos lenguajes que no tienen representación (o es muy baja) en SO (en tods los idiomas) como por ejemplo SAP. Si tuviese que considerar esto un problema (que no es el caso), la solución que ofrecería sería que la búsqueda de SO incluyese contenido fuera de la red SO.

> ¿En qué gastas más tiempo buscando una respuesta? ¿Cómo mejorarías este proceso?

Pensando la mejor cadena de búsqueda para obtener el resultado que necesito. En algunos casos la búsqueda no da el resultado esperado no por falta de respuestas si no por no saber redactar la pregunta. Como la gran mayoría de veces busco a través de Google, SO no puede hacer nada por solucionar esto, pero si el motor de búsqueda de SO fuese más especializado que el de Google (y pudiese relacionar términos de manera más eficiente) el buscador interno sería más atractivo que el externo y aliviaría el peso de la búsqueda de la cadena exacta.

> ¿Cuál es el problema común que la mayoría de los desarrolladores de habla hispana experimentan?

Falta de contenido en Español.

> ¿Qué impide a la comunidad crear una base de conocimiento gratuita en el idioma español? ¿Como resolverías este problema?

Falta de comunicación; seguro que hay muchas personas con conocimientos increíbles que podrían colaborar para compartir conocimiento (en cualquier medio: SO, Youtube, Twitter) pero no se conocen entre si. Cualquier cosa que conecte a más personas podría ser un paso a solucionar el problema.

> ¿Le preguntas a tus colegas de programación "fuera de línea"?

Rara vez.

Comment: No acabo de estar de acuerdo con lo de _Un usuario experimentado en SOen con un medallero y reputación consolidados, no querría empezar de cero en un sitio con la misma temática_. Yo tengo bastante en SO y aquí poquita, pero eso precisamente hace que me apetezca más responder para ir consiguiendo privilegios. Sí que es un poco coñazo tener que ganarte incluso lo de ver el desglose de votos, pero con un poco de intensidad se consigue rápidamente la reputación necesaria.

Comment: @fedorqui tú puedes hablar por ti, no por los demás ¡hay de todo en el mundo!. Nunca dije que fuese una certeza que para los usuarios veteranos de SOen empezar de 0 en SOes sea una barrera, lo expresé como teoría que (personalmente) creo que es bastante probable que sea cierta.

Comment: (No se empieza de 0 sino de 101) Claro que hablo por mí. Ahora, para formular hipótesis es bueno basarlo en hechos, de ahí que sería bueno contrastarlo con personas que estén en esta situación, para ver si tu sensación tiende a ser generalmente cierta, para en tal caso ver qué se puede hacer. En [spanish.se] precisamente hace poco se mencionó que el hecho de que todo el mundo tenga _buena_ reputación es un desincentivo para muchos, que no se ven tan empujados a participar. Al fin y al cabo, todo este sistema juega con la ludificación y un usuario con mucha rep no tiene demasiado incentivo.

Comment: La hipótesis está formulada: "*Los usuarios veteranos de SOen que podrían participar en SOes, no lo hacen por la "pereza" de empezar de 0 (o de 101, o de 5)*". Para lo que sirven los hechos no es para formular hipótesis, si no para confirmarlas. En mi caso tengo 7k en SOen y el triple en SOes (en menos tiempo), mi incentivo fue que me expreso mejor en Español, pero no juzgar a todo el mundo por mi propio patrón.

Comment: Tienes razón, releí tu respuesta y sí veo que lo planteas como hipótesis. En mi primera lectura entendí que lo dabas por hecho, siento la confusión.

Comment: Hablando se entiende la gente :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. ¿Qué problemas experimentas personalmente al buscar respuestas a sus preguntas de programación en el idioma español en Internet? ¿Qué causa la mayor frustración? ¿Cómo mejorarías esto?

Estoy de acuerdo [con Killbuny](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4095/65) en que encontrar respuestas en español es especialmente complejo debido a la mayor diversidad de formas de expresarnos sin embargo no creo que en un espacio abierto e incluyente como este podamos hacer un acuerdo como el que propone para los títulos y cuerpo de las preguntas y respuestas en general pero confío en que sí podemos hacerlo en cuanto a las preguntas/respuestas canónicas y las principales etiquetas.

> 2. ¿Dónde encuentras respuestas en las preguntas de programación de hoy? ¿Qué ves como el principal problema en estos sitios? ¿Cómo los resolverías?

Principalmente las encuentro en los Stack Overflow y en Mozilla Developer Network pero también en blogs y sitios de programación que encuentro usando Google. En el caso de Stack Overflow el principal problema es que las preguntas populares tienen muchas repuestas y en ocasiones las mejores respuestas por ser más recientes quedan "enterradas" es decir, logran pocas vistas y por ende una puntuación baja.

Otro problema molesto son las preguntas tipo carnada de click (click bait). Me refiero a la que tienen títulos "maravillosos" que hace que tengan muchas vistas, especialmente de usuarios que no pueden comentar ni votar, pero contenido terrible.

En Mozilla Developer Network el contenido en español no está tan completo como la versión en inglés, y en algunas ocasiones no está actualizado.

> 3. ¿En qué gastas más tiempo buscando una respuesta? ¿Cómo mejorarías este proceso?

Supongo que en familiarizarme con el lenguaje técnico específico y entender la lógica / pragmatismo asociados para asegurarme que lo sugerido en lo encontrado no introducirá una "hipoteca de código" / "defecto oculto" (code debt / code smell). Ni idea en cómo mejorarlo sin quedar entrampado.

> 4. ¿Cuál es el problema común que la mayoría de los desarrolladores de habla hispana experimentan?

¿El no saber cómo expresar sus preguntas en inglés?

> 5. ¿Qué impide a la comunidad crear una base de conocimiento gratuita en el idioma español? Como resolverías este problema?

La pregunta es demasiado amplia :P

> 6. ¿Le preguntas a tus colegas de programación "fuera de línea"? ¿Cómo se ve este proceso? ¿Cómo mejorarías este proceso?

Rara vez. Ni idea.